# Python Concatenate and stack many matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I want to create a [square matrix like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Dpw.jpg) where its element is a square matrix either the B square matrix or the negative identity matrix or zeros. I have created the B matrix as well as the -I and also I have created a Z matrix of zeros. B, I and Z squares matrices with same n1*n1 (or n2 * n2) dimensions and the final matrix I want to have n*n dimensions where n = n1 * n2

If for example B, I and Z are 4*4 the final will be 16*16

I know how to concatenate and stack matrices but I don't know how to implement this better since need to make the below process 64! times.

```
for iter in range(64):
if iter == 0:
    temp = B
    temp = np.hstack((temp, I))
    temp = np.hstack((temp, Z))
    temp = np.hstack((temp, Z))
if iter == 1:
    temp2 = I
    temp2 = np.hstack((temp2, B))
    temp2 = np.hstack((temp2, I))
    temp2 = np.hstack((temp2, Z))
if iter == 2:
    temp3 = Z
    temp3 = np.hstack((temp3, I))
    temp3 = np.hstack((temp3, B))
    temp3 = np.hstack((temp3, I))
if iter == 3:
    temp4 = Z
    temp4 = np.hstack((temp4, Z))
    temp4 = np.hstack((temp4, I))
    temp4 = np.hstack((temp4, B)) 
    .......
    ........
    ........

st1 = np.vstack((temp, temp2))
st2 = np.vstack((st1, temp3))
.......
```

Can I save n*n matrices into array elements and then concatenate or stack them?

Comment: What you're looking for is a block toeplitz matrix, take a look at [Toeplitz matrix of toeplitz matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464191/toeplitz-matrix-of-toeplitz-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you are dealing with `numpy` arrays or lists, you can use the following example to append arrays:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[11.1, 12.1, 13.1], [21.1, 22.1, 23.1]])
print(x.shape)
y = np.array([[11.2, 12.2],[21.2, 22.2]])
print(y.shape)
z = np.append(x,y, axis=1)
print(z.shape)
print(z)
```

Please note that as mentioned by @user2699, the `numpy` append could get slow for large array sizes ([Fastest way to grow a numpy numeric array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133885/fastest-way-to-grow-a-numpy-numeric-array)).

With lists, you can use the append command:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x.append([4, 5])
print (x) #
```

This example is taken from: [Difference between append vs. extend list methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: Just a note, `np.append` should not be used in situations like this one where multiple arrays are being joined sequentially, for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133885/fastest-way-to-grow-a-numpy-numeric-array

Comment: `np.append` is a poorly named cover function for `np.concatenate`.  In this case the arrays already have the right number of dimensions: `np.concatenate((x,y),axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`np.block` helps you create an array like this:

```
In [109]: B =np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2)                                        
In [110]: I =np.eye(2).astype(int)                                              
In [111]: Z = np.zeros((2,2),int)                                               
In [112]: np.block?                                                             
In [113]: np.block([[B,I,Z,Z],[I,B,I,Z],[Z,I,B,I],[Z,Z,I,B]])                   
Out[113]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4]])
```

`block` does a nested sequence of `concatenate` starting with the innermost lists.  Previous versions used `hstack` on the inner lists, and `vstack` of those results.

```
In [118]: np.vstack((np.hstack([B,I,Z,Z]),np.hstack([I,B,I,Z])))                
Out[118]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

The lists of lists in `[113]` could be constructed with code, using the desired sizes, but I won't go into those details.

Another approach is to create a `np.zeros((8,8))` target array, and fill in the desired blocks.  Maybe even better to make a `np.zeros((4,2,4,2))`, fill that, and reshape later.

```
In [119]: res = np.zeros((4,2,4,2),int)                                         
In [120]: res[np.arange(4),:,np.arange(4),:] = B                                
In [121]: res[np.arange(3),:,np.arange(1,4),:] = I                              
In [122]: res[np.arange(1,4),:,np.arange(3),:] = I  
In [124]: res.reshape(8,8)                                                      
Out[124]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4]])
```